# How to create filled chart with marked vertical lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, charts

I would like to create filled chart similar to this image with marked gray vertical dotted lines.

[image]

Comment: I'm too lazy to make a proper answer right now, but search for `\closedcycle` in the `pgpflots` manual to make the filled part. For the dashed lines, make a second plot with `ycomb`. If you get stuck, post the code you got, and someone will be able to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, so I will check `pgfplots` documentation.

Comment: You mean you didn't before? But you tagged it `pgfplots`.

Comment: I didn't use `\closedcycle` before.